# Flask web development. No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm working with Flask following Miguel Grinberg's book at the moment. i've reached the part where i need to interact with MySQL. i've checked everything and yet when i try to create the actual database with the command:

db.create_all()

i get an error saying "No module named 'MySQLdb'". i've tried installing mySQL-python in my virtual environment and i get another error - "No module named 'ConfigParser'". i tried installing that module with pip, but the same error occurs like i didn't install the ConfigParser module at all. any advice? i'm using python version 3.4. i've read a couple of times that MySQLdb doesn't work with python 3, a statement which contradicts what was written in Miguels book, that Flask is compatible both with python 2 and 3.

Comment: You need to use a different MySQL driver, like [`pymysql`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/).

Answer (score 0):

solved it. needed to install mysqlclient via pip in the virtual environment. mySQL-python apparently doesn't work with python3